# pre_get_posts Remove posts based on meta value with 'post__not_in'

Tags: user-roles, user-access, pre-get-posts

I am attempting to alter the query of pages where the post meta value of `_members_access_role` does not meet that of the currently logged-in user. Here is what I have so far:

```
// Get all posts with the access level of 'Member'
function members_get_member_posts() {
    $post_ids = array();
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => array('post','tribe_events','document'),
        'meta_key' => '_members_access_role',
        'meta_value' => 'member',
        'post_status' => array('publish','private')
    );
    $protected_posts = get_posts($args);
    if($protected_posts) {
        foreach($protected_posts as $p) {
            $post_ids[] = $p->ID;
        }
    }
    // return an array of paid post IDs
    return $post_ids;
}

// Hide all posts from users who are not logged-in or are not administrators or members
function members_hide_member_posts($query) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(empty($current_user) || ($current_user->roles[0] != 'member' && $current_user->roles[0] != 'administrator') && (false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])) {
        $protected_posts = members_get_member_posts();
        if($protected_posts)
            $query->set('post__not_in', $protected_posts);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'members_hide_member_posts');
```

If I do a quick `print_r(members_get_member_posts())` I am seeing the array of post IDs correctly - but on the front-end, posts are still showing up when they should not be (since I am feeding in that returned function value to `posts__not_in`).

For example, if a public user visits the site, they can still see the Member (role) posts. Was also having a bit of trouble bringing in `global $current_user` object -- as it would not check if `$current_user->ID` was empty or not without the page producing a fatal error about memory limits (even after I set the php.ini file to 256M for the hell of it), so a possible memory leak? Thanks!

*Update*
While not documented, I did double-check that you can use an `array()` value for `post_type` in get_posts as of 3.3 (I believe). Also tried without it and returns just posts as it should - so the data is returning, just not "filtering out" that data.

Comment: what is the suppress filters check for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this version:

```
// Get all posts with the access level of 'Member'
function members_get_member_posts() {

    $post_ids = wp_cache_get( 'wpse61487_members_posts' );
    if ( false === $post_ids ) {

        $post_ids = array();
        $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'any',
            'meta_key' => '_members_access_role',
            'meta_value' => 'member',
            'post_status' => array('publish','private')
        );

        $protected_posts = get_posts($args);
        if($protected_posts) {
            $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $protected_posts, 'ID' );
        }

        wp_cache_set( 'wpse61487_members_posts', $post_ids );
     }

     // return an array of paid post IDs
     return $post_ids;
}

// Hide all posts from users who are not logged-in or are not administrators or members
function members_hide_member_posts($query) {

    if( !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(empty($current_user) || ($current_user->roles[0] != 'member' && $current_user->roles[0] != 'administrator') && (false === $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])) {
        $protected_posts = members_get_member_posts();
        if( !empty( $protected_posts ) )
            $query->set('post__not_in', $protected_posts);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'members_hide_member_posts');
```

Comment: Aha! So it was running this on every query on the page that was causing the memory issue - awesome! I adjusted the `pre_get_posts()` action slightly (as it wasn't checking if a user was logged-in or not correctly http://pastebin.com/x0mkzaTE -- my bad), but this also bring up one minor detail I left out. If I did in-fact want this `pre_get_posts()` action to effect a widget that would have recent posts (for example), any recommendations on that? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you only want to target that one widget or also target the widget?

Comment: Hey Pippin - Also target widgets. Seeing how to specifically target widgets would be very interesting too. Thanks!

Comment: To target all queries, just remove `if( !$query->is_main_query() ) return;`

Comment: Great place to use caching as well!

Comment: @StephenHarris Actually would love it if you could expand a bit more on the best way to do that. Thing is that removing the check for `is_main_query()` "would" work, but causing some memory allocation issues (even after increasing the PHP memory limit to a ridiculous amount (512M)). Should I start a new question for that?

Comment: Just edited the answer to include caching. It will only run that query once per page load. I'm not sure if transients might be better here...? Would persistence be desirable, anyone?

Comment: Also, as in my comment on the question, I don't think the `$query->query_vars['suppress_filters']` check is necessary / desirable - I think it might be a hangover from its incorrect use in lieu of `$query->is_main_query()`.

Comment: is_main_query() will return true on some secondary queries, which is why the suppress_filters check can be necessary, though it really is only needed if you have some queries that you do NOT want affected.

Comment: @StephenHarris Ah appreciate the caching addition - I think that transients might be a better way to go as when new posts are added, we'll need to re-generate that query - possibly deleted after every page save? Or we could just clear the cache just as easily on page-save as well http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: @Pippin `$query->is_main_query()` only returns true for the main query, unless you are using `query_posts`. The `suppress_filter` has nothing to do with the main query and can be over-ridden in a `WP_Query` / `get_posts()`.

Comment: @Zach. The cache will expire after every page load. Using transients will require you to clear the cache whenever a post is updated/deleted. This isn't considered that bad since slower load times admin side is preferable to having it on the front.

Comment: @StephenHarris Gotcha - when removing the `is_main_query()` check am always getting memory issues (as mentioned, set this to a ridiculously high limit, 512M to check). Also - shouldn't `$result` be `$post_ids` in your example?

Comment: @Zach Yes, updated answer. WP should be able to handle it with caching (probably should be able to without) - it'll depend on your other plugins/themes too.

Comment: @StephenHarris Just tried on a vanilla WP install and still getting memory allocation issues -- if you have a moment, could you test on your end?

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /Users/studio/Sites/wpm/wp-includes/query.php on line 2941